# References to Microsoft.Bcl patched libraries (System.Runtime, etc) are not added during build on some machines

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, .net-4.0

We recently added Microsoft.Bcl.Async to our Solution using NuGet.

This works totally fine on two machines. However, on two different machines, the compiled assemblies lack references to the patched .NET assemblies that are shipped with Microsoft.Bcl (System.Runtime, System.IO, etc.). All machines run Visual Studio 2015. The references are visible in the project files and in Visual Studio, they just don't get compiled into the assemblies (I wrote a small tool for that, querying the result from Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies.

If I run the binaries compiled by one of the 'broken' computers on Windows XP, it doesn't work, because Microsoft.Bcl isn't actually included.

We've already tried getting a fresh copy in a new workspace and even reinstalling Visual Studio, but the build is still broken.

EDIT:
I found the following lines in the build output:

```
16>CSC : warning CS1685: The predefined type 'INotifyCompletion' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
16>CSC : warning CS1685: The predefined type 'IAsyncStateMachine' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
16>CSC : warning CS1685: The predefined type 'AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<TResult>' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
16>CSC : warning CS1685: The predefined type 'ICriticalNotifyCompletion' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
16>CSC : warning CS1685: The predefined type 'AsyncTaskMethodBuilder' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

I am not quite sure yet how to resolve this, so help is appreciated, but I think, this might be the problem I am facing.

Comment: Ultimately, I suspect it will be very hard to get any official support to help with this: Windows XP is end of life, .NET 4.0 is end of life, Visual Studio 2015 is *outdated* (but Update 3 has mainstream support until 10/13/2020, and extended support until 2025)

Comment: My crystal ball says that the "broken" computers use the wrong reference assemblies.  The ones from c:\windows\microsoft.net instead of c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies.  So don't actually target .NET 4.0

Comment: @HansPassant Nope, that is not the case. However, I just found something interesting after looking into the build output myself. I will update the question.

Comment: INotifyCompletion and friends were not added to mscorlib until version 4.5.  Wrong reference assembly.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, that is also something that threw me off. But how exactly would I resolve this?

Comment: You'll have to move over a bit, the crystal ball can't see your screen.  Consider posting the compile command line so we can see what is getting passed.  And of course consider comparing good vs bad machine.  And ask the owners of those machines if they used any sledgehammers lately, programmers tend to solve compile problems they don't understand and can't test the wrong way.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, I guess I can't do that anymore, as my colleague already fixed the problem using some brute force. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess the problem resolved itself. "Broken" computer 1 apparently wasn't broken or was and magically isn't anymore and computer 2 is now fixed, after a wild ride of uninstalling everything .NET related and reinstalling Visual Studio.

It is kind of disappointing that I am now not able to properly diagnose the source of this problem, but I will just have to live with that.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.